# Choose Function Through Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Assume the following two functions may or may not be provided by the user:

```
void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo int" << std::endl; }
void foo() { std::cout << "foo void" << std::endl; }
```

In my implementation, I want to call `foo(int)` if the user defined it, and `foo()` otherwise. This can be done as follows:

```
template<class Int> auto call_foo(Int i) -> decltype(foo(i)) { return foo(i); }
template<class... Int> void call_foo(Int... i) { return foo(); }
```

If, however, we want to do the opposite, i.e. prefer `foo()` over `foo(int)`, the following naive attempt does not work.

```
template<class Int> auto call_foo(Int i) -> decltype(foo()) { return foo(); }
template<class... Int> void call_foo(Int... i) { return foo(i...); }
```

The problem is that `decltype(foo())` does not depend on `Int`, so the possible non-existence of `foo()` does not result in SFINAE.

A possible solution is to require the user to define either of

```
void foo(int, void*) { std::cout << "foo int" << std::endl; }
void foo(void*) { std::cout << "foo void" << std::endl; }
```

Like this, we always have a parameter of `foo` on which we can do the "template vs. parameter-pack" trick. While this technically solves the problem, it's quite ugly as it requires the user to take an additional parameter whose meaning might not be obvious to him/her. So is there a way to achieve the same effect *without* the additional parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following may help:

```
template<typename ... Ts> void foo(Ts...) = delete;
void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo int" << std::endl; }
//void foo() { std::cout << "foo void" << std::endl; }

namespace detail
{

struct overload_priority_low {};
struct overload_priority_high : overload_priority_low{};

template <typename Int>
auto call_foo(Int i, overload_priority_low) -> decltype(foo(i)) { return foo(i); }

template <typename Int>
auto call_foo(Int , overload_priority_high) -> decltype(sizeof(Int), foo()) { return foo(); }

}

void call_foo(int i)
{
    return detail::call_foo(i, detail::overload_priority_high{});
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/eyKW1y).

Comment: Very useful trick, this tag inheritance. I cleaned your code up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176516/choose-best-available-function-through-tag-inheritance

Comment: @MarcoA.: Removing the `=delete` seems to fix the error with clang.

Answer (score 4):

No need for SFINAE. Just standard overload resolution is sufficient.

```
void call_func(void (*f)(), int) { f(); } // #1

template<class = void>
void call_func(void (*f)(int), int x) { f(x); } // #2

call_func(foo, 1); // #1 is preferred if viable. All others being equal,
                   // non-templates are preferred over templates
```

Comment: +1. Although I was hoping to see a nice TMP solution which would work for a user specified precedence. For example, if he has `N` `foo`'s which all take the corresponding number of `int`s, and the user wants to specify some permutation of `{1,...,N}` as the precedence order. Of course, I don't see any practical significance. Just that it would lead to some interesting code :)

Comment: You may use *tag inheritance* to order multiple overload (and avoid template).

Comment: Your solution is perfect for the situation I described in the question. Unfortunately, in the actual code I have more than two functions and not all of them have the same name. Then, you do need SFINAE to rule out the non-existing names.

Comment: @Pradhan You find something in that direction here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176516/choose-best-available-function-through-tag-inheritance