# How can I make C++ prefer to match a parent class overload instead of a template?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, class-hierarchy

```
class Parent {};

class Child : public Parent {};

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo (Parent &) {};

    template <typename T>
    Foo (const T &);
};

int main ()
{
    Child c;

    Foo foo (c);
}
```

This produces a linker error since the constructor for `foo` chooses `template<typename T>Foo::Foo(const T &)` instead of `Foo::Foo(Parent&)`.

If `c` has type `Parent` instead of `Child`, this uses the non-template constructor and links with no issues.

I can work around this with

```
Foo foo ((Parent&) c);
```

but I don't want to do that.

Why does C++ prefer to use a template instead of implicitly casting `c` to `Parent&`?

Can I change the class to prefer casting to templating, so the workaround is not needed?

Comment: While `Child` is-a `Parent`, there's still no *direct* match to `Parent&`. Therefore the templated version is a better match.

Comment: One solution is to create a matching constructor `Foo (Child&) {};`.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176516/choose-best-available-function-through-tag-inheritance

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to disable the template constructor through SFINAE:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Parent, T>> * = 0
>
Foo (const T &);
```

Comment: Maybe play also with `const`, as `const Parent parent; Foo{parent};` matches no constructors (OP uses `Foo (Parent &)` and `Foo (const T&)`...).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler prefers to choose the template constructor with `T=child` because overload resolution considers that a qualification conversion (adding `const` to the argument type) is better than a derived to base conversion.

So the simplest way is just to declare a constructor taking a child as argument:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo (Parent &) {};

    Foo (Child & x):Foo(static_cast<Parent&>(x)) {};

    template <typename T>
    Foo (const T &);
};
```

Notice that if the argument to the constructor is a const lvalue or an rvalue, then as in your example code the template constructor will be selected. I suppose that this is intentional.

Comment: `Foo` doesn't know about any subclasses of `Parent`